# Show that for $w,x,y,z\in{R^+}$, if $(w+y)(x+z)=wy+xz$ then $ \frac{w}{x}+\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{w}≥8$

Tags: inequality

I know usually that  $ \frac{w}{x}+\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{w}≥4$ by the AM-GM inequality however this one has a separate condition that is throwing me off. I tried to combine the fractions into $\frac{wz+yz}{xz}+\frac{xw+zy}{yw}$ to sub in the equality $(w+y)(x+z)=wy+xz$ but it doesn't seem to come out because I can't find the $8$ in any way that I combine them.

How can I show this inequality, is it even still by AM-GM?

Comment: This is IMO Shortlist 2020 A3.

Comment: HInt: Equality holds when $ w = y, x = z, w^2 + x^2 = 4wx$. Use this to backtrack.

Answer (score 2):

This is a cute problem - I will give you a hint. Write the given condition as:
$$\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{w}{y}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{y}{w}}\right)\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{z}{x}} +\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{z}}\right) = \sqrt{\dfrac{wy}{xz}} + \sqrt{\dfrac{xz}{wy}}.$$

If you now notice $a+\frac 1a\geq 2$ for $a > 0,$ and use this on the LHS of the above, you get a lower of $4$ bound for the RHS. Then, you could smartly use AM-GM on your expression to chain these bounds to get an $8.$ You can then see that the equality is attained for infinitely many pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an elaboration of my hint in the comments, in particular the "use this to backtrack".
While it essentially is the same as dezdichado's solution, it explains how one can arrive at a solution, instead of just being very lucky of noticing their hint.

1. Playing around with the given condition and try to guess when the equality condition (to the inequality) holds. EG Like you mentioned, the naive AM-GM with $w=x=y=z$ leads to lower bound of 4, but it doesn't satisfy the given condition.
   After a while, you should notice that one case of the minimum occurs when $ w = y, x = z$. The given condition then becomes $ 4xy = x^2 + y^2$, and the expression we want to minimize is $ 2 \frac{ x^2+y^2}{xy} = 8 $.
2. The equality condition is  $ \frac{x}{y} = \frac{ 4 \pm \sqrt{ 20}}{2} $ (The exact value isn't needed, just that it's real).
   Note in particular that $ x \neq y$. So we can't naively apply AM-GM to all of the terms.
   How can we exploit $w = y, x = z$ in the expression?
3. There isn't much that we can do to the given condition under the constraints of the equality condition.
   One possible application of inequalities is:

> $$ wy + xz = (w+y)(x+z) \geq 2\sqrt{wy} \times 2 \sqrt {xz} = 4 \sqrt{wyxz}.$$

Note that the naive AM-GM of $ wy + xz \geq 2 \sqrt{wyxz}$ is much weaker, so this is very encouraging.
In particular, it might be enough for us to double the naive lower bound of 4 to the actual minimum of 8.

4. How can we apply this inequality condition to the expression, which is homogenous of degree 0? Maybe let's make the inequality also homogenous of degree 0:

> $$ \sqrt{\frac{wy}{xz} } + \sqrt{\frac{ xz}{wy}} \geq 4 . $$

5. Now, it's almost immediate to see that

$$ \frac{w}{x} + \frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{z} + \frac{z}{w} \geq 2 (\sqrt{\frac{wy}{xz} } + \sqrt{\frac{ xz}{wy}} ) \geq 8 . $$

Note: The following terms have the same meaning throughout my writeup.

- given condition: $(w+y)(x+z) = wy+xz$.
- Expression: $ \frac{w}{x} + \frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{z} + \frac{z}{w} $.
- Equality condition: The equality condition where the expression achieves its minimum.
- Inequality condition: An inequality that we will derive based on the equality condition.